# Firebase logout show Permission denied error.

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

So whenever I logout from Firebase, I got coupled

```
Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

I understand it is because login session is terminated, some of my objects cannot access firebase data any more. But how can I disconnect this objects before logout?

For logout button in one of my Ionic View, it just call a firebase service:

```
function logout() {
      auth.$unauth();
      getCurrentUser();
};
function getCurrentUser() {
        var authData = auth.$getAuth();
        if (authData) {
            $rootScope.userId = authData.uid;
            $rootScope.currentUser = $firebaseObject(authRef.child("users").child(authData.uid));
            return $rootScope.currentUser;
        } else {
          console.log("User is not login!");
          $rootScope.userId = null;
          $location.path("/auth/signin");
          if ($rootScope.currentUser) {
            $rootScope.currentUser.$destroy();
          } 
        }
    };
```

So I destroy the $rootScope.currentUser there. I use the same getCurrentUser for profile page. So the Error did not show up this way. But when in other views, which I have another $firebaseArray, and also another Ref.on("child_added", function(snap) with the same $firebaseObject. When I view the profile page, then this page with at least 3 firebase connection, I got 3 permission_denied Errors when I logout (logout button is on user profile page).

My question is, how do I disconnect this firebase connection before I logout? Is there a way disconnect ALL the firebase connection - no matter AngularFire or regular Firebase? So I can logout without worry about which firebase connection I have no close yet? Also, since the Logout button is in Profile scope and the others connection is in a different scope, I have no idea how to close the connection which is not even in the profile scope...

Comment: are you doing anything using "$onAuth"? Maybe in your auth factory?

Comment: Yes I do. But using onAuth still won't know what I should close when logout.  As my instances are everywhere. And most of them I can't close when leave view since they all need to listen to update from firebase.

Answer (score 2):

You need to destroy all the firebase references on logout.
Something like this.

**In logout function.**

```
function logout() {
       auth.$unauth();
       $rootScope.$broadcast('logout');
};
```

**In controller**

```
vm.profile = authService.profile(user.uid); // FirebaseObject Reference
vm.parties = partyService.getPartiesByUser(user.uid); // FirebaseArray Reference

$rootScope.$on('logout', function () {
  vm.parties.$destroy();
  vm.profile.$destroy();
});
```

Comment: This can be a solution. But using $rootscope just seem a little hacky.

Comment: Using $rootScope you can broadcast logout event in all the controllers.

Comment: If you destroy your firebase references, you need some way to reinitialize your factory/services/controllers where your references are defined.  If you don't, no data once you logout and log back in.

Answer (score 0):

well, i guess you have a button to logout.
so in your function logout() you'd first $destroy the data object, somehow wait (whichs' best practice i'm trying to figure out), and then authref.unauth();
i'd say

Comment: All - I had the same issue and the quick fix was to update the rules {".read": true}, only for read access, somewhat similar post you can get an idea to resolve it in a simple way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules There are some more examples to resolve this by writing a decorator and destroy all firebase references created with $firebaseArray and $firebaseObject.

Answer (score -1):

You need destroy the firebase ref for the object that you saved data previously. How?

Before, I initialize my var songs like:
this.songs = this.af.list('/songs');

When I signOut(), I should destroy the reference of the variable that I initialized so that I execute:

this.songs.$ref.off();

With this line, your problem