# Firebase Security Rules?

Tags: json, node.js, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I seem to be having a hard time with firebase security rules. I've read the guides, but the simulator results aren't descriptive enough (Would be much easier if we could just hover over a node, and a button pops up where we can update the rules).

Here's what my structure looks like:

```
chats
  - randomChatId01
    - name: "awesome chat"
    - members:
        - userId01 : true
        - userId02 : true
  - randomChatId02
    - members:
        - userId02 : true
  - randomChatId03
    - members:
        - userId01 : true
        - userId02 : true
  - ...
```

I only want a user to be able to read the chat nodes in which the node's child node *members* contains the authenticated user's *auth.uid*.

So in this case if *userId01* were logged in, she would only have read access to *randomChatId01* and *randomChatId03*.

This is the rule I have:

```
{
    "rules": {

        "chats": {

          "$chat": {
            ".read": "data.child('members').val().contains(auth.uid)"
          }
        }
    }
}
```

However it's returning the following in the simulator:

```
Attempt to read /chats with auth={"provider":"anonymous","uid":"eF4ztDEXz7"}
    /
    /chats

No .read rule allowed the operation.
Read was denied.
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because Firebase Security Rules are evaluated at the location that you read from.

You're trying to read `/chats`. The user does not have read permission to `/chats`, so the operations fails straight away.

If you read `/chats/randomChatId01` as `userId01` it will succeed.

This is covered in the documentation section [rules are not filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter). Also see Michael Lehenbauer's answer here: [Restricting child/field access with security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules)