# Filtering Firebase results

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have a path in a Firebase project with a collection of `thing`s in it. Each `thing` has an `owner` property. I want to allow users to access the `/things` path, but they should only see the `thing`s that have their `auth.uid` as `owner`. Using security rules, I can limit the `/things/$thing` path to only be readable by the `owner`, however users can still see all `thing`s listed at `/things` regardless of whether or not they are the `owner` for each child. How do I only display a subset of the children?

Comment: Instead of describing the problem please add an mvc (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the problem and what you already have tried

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!