# Allowing anonymous access to list of just public objects

Tags: firebase

I have a list of objects I call playsets. Some of these are public. How do I let anonymous users get a listing of only public objects? I thought it was `".read": "data.child('public').val() == true"`, but I got an access denied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a separate list of the publicly accessible objects, since [rules are not filter](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter).

For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103).