# Filtering and Permissions in Firebase

Tags: security, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37470879/1148702) about my Firebase implementation. Essentially, I was trying to structure my Firebase database so that I could have a collection of objects, with some users accessing a subset of these objects.

In my example, I have tasks. Multiple users will use this database, and per Firebase's suggestion, all the tasks for all users are [flattened](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) as children of one parent node. Each user can access their own tasks, indicated by a `creatorId` in a `task` object. Perhaps in the future permissions could be extended so tasks could be shared with other users. But for now, just ownership and the creator can read and write their own `tasks`.

This is trivial to implement using [queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html). I'm no security expert, but it seems to me that somehow enforcing these rules separate from queries inside client implementation is an important security consideration. Even if my client limits access in this way, and *all* access requires authentication with our custom token provider, it seems possible that someone (another authenticated user) could figure out how we are retrieving our data, and access other users' tasks.

I know [Rules Are Not Filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103) too), but it seems reasonable that one would want to secure data access in roughly this way.

My questions:

- Is this simply not a meaningful security concern?
- If it is, is there a Firebase-like way to do what I'm describing? In Firebase's [security example](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html), it would be like users wouldn't be able to access *all* rooms or messages. That seems like a perfectly reasonable software design decision (private rooms, messages in private rooms, etc.)
- Am I just totally missing something here, or not understanding the situation, or architecting this in a very naïve way?

Edit:

I think the first time I read I [Structuring Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html), I missed "Using Indices to Define Complex Relationships", which addresses this point.

Comment: This would indeed be solved by adding an index for each user with the keys of the items they can access. If that is what you were looking for, can you add a self-answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first time I read I [Structuring Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html), I missed "Using Indices to Define Complex Relationships", which addresses this point.

What I want to do here is, as Frank van Puffelen [clarifies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727782/filtering-and-permissions-in-firebase?noredirect=1#comment62928457_37727782), on my various `user` objects, add a list of keys for items that each user can access.

This won't change much (except duplicating storing these relationships) when I update or upload items.

When fetching and listening for `.ChildChanged` events, however, I think instead of setting up one `observeEventType` handler for all of one type of object, I'll have one handler for each individual object a user has access to.