# Cannot read all data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read all data from my firebase
but I canno do this

Here is my code:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('users/').on('value',function(snapshot)                   {
  window.alert(snapshot.val());
});
```

and my firebase look like this:

```
"users":    
{

  "uid": {

    "username": "AAA",
    "email": "aaa@a.com"
  },

  "uid": {

    "username": "ZZZ",
    "email": "zzz@z.com"
  }

}
```

### I can't get anything data using this code

update

I have defined my security in firebase

```
{
 "rules":{

  "users":{

    "$uid": {
      // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
      ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid ",      
      //".write": "auth !== null && (auth.uid === $uid || auth.uid ==='0127a226-83ec-4eae-bbc7-53b81da10c0d')",

      // grants read access to any user who is logged in with an email and password
      ".read": "auth !== null &&  auth.uid ===$uid "
      //".read": "auth !== null &&  (auth.uid ===$uid  || auth.uid ==='0127a226-83ec-4eae-bbc7-53b81da10c0d')"

      //".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['full_name','uid','state_light'])"   
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: See my answer and if that doesn't fix it, how is your initial firebase reference defined?

Comment: A new Firebase Database created on console.firebase.google.com nowadays requires a user to be authenticated before they can read data. Most likely you don't have permission to read the data. A quick way to see if that is the cause, is to add a error handler to your `on()` call: `on('value', ..., function(error) { console.error(error); }` and check the JavaScript console of your browser.

Comment: it show error and i post my security in thread

Comment: Can you remove your rules and set .read and .write both to true under the main rules node? That will verify if the rules are causing the issue.

Comment: i think not the rules problem, because i have app using the same rules, but it can read/write correctly

Comment: Rules are not filters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/6680611

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restricting child/field access with security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the extraneous / from .child('users/') and format it like so

```
firebase.database().ref('users').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  window.alert(snapshot.val());
});
```

Also, in your firebase structure, you can't have two keys with the same name (uid).

Comment: still cannot read data
oh the uid just the example
i am using firebase tutorial to defined firebase

and i add a code
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();