# Can't understand Firebase database rules

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This must be something easy to be done, and I'm doing something stupid, but for 4 hours I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I have databse entity like this:

```
posts:
    -KK-3ajDuSUglnMMdXgy
       authorId: "DYI4TPbwQocFsVROStUqcGNFHhW2"
       authorName: "john"
       privacy: "PrivacyTypeWorld"
       text: "some post text"
```

Post can have 3 levels of privacy: for all (PrivacyTypeWorld), only for author (PrivacyTypePrivate), and for friends (friendId, friendId, ...).

My security rules look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
     "posts": {
        ".read": "auth != null && (data.child('privacy').val() === 'PrivacyTypeWorld')",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
   }
}
```

But with this rules I see nothing. If I set `".read": "auth != null"` - all works fine. 
What I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**

To retrieve data I use:

```
_refHandle = [[_ref child:@"posts"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded
                                      withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
                [_arrPosts addObject:snapshot];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_arrPosts.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
          }];
```

Comment: You're missing a level in your rules. To access each node, you need a variable... in this case $post_id for example, then you can reference (speaking generically) $post_id/privacy = 'whatever'. See [Secure Your Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data) about 1/2 way down in the Structuring Your Rules section. Otherwise you are looking for posts/privacy where is should be posts/post_id/privacy.

Comment: Can you add the code that is not working to your question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, code of what? I can see in Firebase console that data actually added (https://www.dropbox.com/s/shbfrob1af8o405/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202016-06-11%2023.03.07.png?dl=0) and rules loojs like in adolfosrs answer

Comment: @daleijn he means your swift code. how are you trying to retrieve the data...

Comment: @adolfosrs, updated question

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes:

1. your rules define access on the wrong level (as @adolfosrs says). It's easiest to understand by realizing that there is no node `posts/privacy`, so that check will always return false. Instead you should grant access on `posts/$postid`, so that you're checking `posts/$postid/privacy`.
2. you are trying to read `posts`. Firebase queries always check the permission on the level where you read/query. Since you're not granting read permission on `posts`, the query will fail.

This last bit is commonly known as ["rules are not filters" or "rules cannot be used to filter data"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters). The best answer about that is [Restricting child/field access with security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules/14298525#14298525).

The easiest solution in your case seems to put the world-readable posts under a separate top-level node where you grant everyone read access:

```
posts:
    -KK-3ajDuSUglnMMdXgy
       authorId: "DYIciaiew98acohzxvx09qw"
       authorName: "puf"
       text: "Only authenticated users can write this"
publicPosts:
    -KK-3ajDuSUglnMMdXgy
       authorId: "DYI4TPbwQocFsVROStUqcGNFHhW2"
       authorName: "john"
       text: "Everyone can read this"
```

This these rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
     "posts": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
     "publicPosts": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: And in case when privacy sets only to some friends (friendId, friendId, ...). How can I implement this? And why @adolfosrs's answer didn't work? I have to change something in my database structure or what?

Comment: But if I set this rule (like in @adolfosrs answer) to .write (only change data -> newData) - this works as expected and I can only add post if 'privacy' === 'PrivacyTypeWorld'. Why this doesn't works for .read?

Comment: When you write, you're writing a specific post (`/posts/-KK-3ajDuSUglnMMdXgy`). But when you're querying, you're reading from the list (`/posts`) where you don't have read permission.

Comment: If each user has access to different posts, you'll have to keep a list of posts (or post ids) that each user has access to. This is quite normal in NoSQL data modeling. I highly recommend spending some time reading [this article on the topic](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: qualifier "data" not for this case (check data that already in database)?

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting into each post. You are looking into privacy inside de posts instead of posts/postId.

In the following rules `$post` is referring to the post id. So you could also work with the post id using the `$post` in your read or write if you want to work with any other validation.

```
{
  "rules": {
     "posts": {
        "$post": {
            ".read": "auth != null && (data.child('privacy').val() === 'PrivacyTypeWorld')",
            ".write": "auth != null"
        }
      }
   }
}
```