# How to allow read/write access to Firebase database with Email Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to read/write data to my Firebase Database with the below security rules. I am confused as I believe I've followed the documentation given by firebase.

I've followed this link -> [FIREBASE USER BASED SECURITY](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-variable)

I only have two child nodes that I am writing to. User data, and a wireless node data that is entered by the user.

```
{
"rules": {
"nodes": {
  "$user_id": {
    ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
  }
},
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: please provide more details on what are you trying. We need a [MVC question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with.

Comment: Re-writing question one moment.

Comment: I don't have much more information that. I followed the firebase documentation, and I'm lost currently. Aside from allowing read/write access true to the whole database. It isn't what I want. Need to have any and all child nodes to be accessible by the authenticated user. Currently only using email/password authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer here. All I'm trying to do is allow authenticated users read/write the data.

this question answer mine after I searched different search queries.

Using [firebase] tag i was able to search through the questions and find this.

[Restricting child/field access with security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules)

Comment: The fact that rules cannot be used to filter data is one of the common sources of confusion for developers new to Firebase. Good to hear that you found it.