# Firebase rules structure with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to develop a simple Chat app using Firebase platform. To show a list of conversations I'm using *FirebaseRecyclerAdapter*. The thing is, that I can't figure out how to properly set the rules so users can only access conversations, that they are members of.

This is what my Firebase DB structure looks like.

```
{
    "conversations": {
        "cid1": {
            "title": "Conversation1"
        },
        "cid2": {...
        },
        "cid3": {...
        }
    },
    "members": {
        "cid1": {
            "uid1": true,
            "uid2": true
        },
        "cid2": {...
        },
        "cid3": {...
        }
    },
    "users": {
        "uid1": {
            "name": "User1"
        },
        "uid2": {...
        },
    }
}
```

And these are the rules I'm trying to apply.

```
  {
    "rules": {
        "conversations": {
            "$conversation_id": {
                ".read": "root.child('members').child($conversation_id).child(auth.uid).exists()",
            }
         },
     }
  }
```

By applying this rules and using *FirebaseRecyclerAdapter* I'm getting this error.

> Listen at /conversations failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

I suppose it's because I'm allowing users to read to conversation element, but not the whole list of conversations. Anybody has an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: what is `mid1`, `mid2`?

Comment: We need to see the code you are using to access it.

Comment: @adolfosrs: It's supposed to be the user id. Edited the structure, so I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: There is not much code to show. I just basically reference the node         mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("conversations/");

and then create the adapter 
new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Conversation, ConversationItemHolder>(
                Conversation.class,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                ConversationItemHolder.class,
                mRef) {...}

Comment: I would start by removing the slash inside `.child("conversations/")`. let it be just `.child("conversations")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're falling for one of the pitfalls in Firebase's security rules: you cannot use security rules to filter data.

Your list adapter is listening to `/conversations`. That read operation will succeed or fail in its entirety, based on whether the user has read permission on `/conversations`.

Since you don't grant read permission on `/conversations` the listener will be cancelled. This is known as [Rules Are Not Filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) in the documentation and has been [covered frequently here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters) (because it's such a common pitfall). For one of the oldest and still best answer, see: [Restricting child/field access with security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules/14298525#14298525)