# Firebase rule that works like a filter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

When using `.read` with a true rule on the Users node, I give access to  some authenticated user read every user listed on that tree. I need just some of then.

I need some rule that works like a filter. So on getting User/ path, this authenticated user will get an users array of **only** those that have permission path like this `$uid > permission > auth.uid = true`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users" : {
      ".read": true,
      "$uid" : {
        ".read" : "(auth != null && auth.uid === $uid) || root.child('Users/'+ $uid+'/permission/'+ auth.uid).val() == true",
        ".write" : false
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules

Answer (score 3):

You can't use rules as filters, they are atomic to the specific branch you are trying to read/write.

Your outer read rule is giving access to the whole `/Users` branch. Removing it and having the userId that you want to read you will get the behavior you are expecting. So, unfortunately this will work only when reading with `ref.child("Users").child(targetUserId).once...`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users" : {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read" : "(auth != null && auth.uid === $uid) || root.child('Users/'+ $uid+'/permission/'+ auth.uid).val() == true",
        ".write" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you want to have, in one single call, the list of user ids that the authenticated user has access to I recommend you to actually save the accessible users inside `/User/userId` instead of having the ones that can read. And your rules will slightly change.

```
 {
      "rules": {
        "Users" : {
          "$uid" : {
            ".read" : "(auth != null && auth.uid === $uid) || root.child('Users/'+ auth.uid +'/accessibleUsers/'+ $uid).val() == true",
            ".write" : false
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Additionally, this can get complex when scaling so, depending on what you plan for you application, you should be thinking of having this accessible users list in a separate branch (outside of Users).

Comment: I get it. I was on the way this [article](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data) says to, so I have faced this problem. I will try your approach.