# Firebase structuring data, keeping some data private

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `users` collection where each user has a bunch of properties

```
users: {
 <userid>: {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    photo: "",
    lastLogin: ""
 }
}
```

With that structure, I want to build a `search` functionality in my app where a user can search for other users.

What I want is for the users collection to be available on the client for searching/filtering but minus the `lastLogin` attribute of each user. That is more like a private attribute.

How does one go about doing that? I literally dont want that attribute to even be sent over the wire.

Comment: what about storing lastLogin in a separate node, i.e. in other subtree than users are stored

Comment: You'll have to split the public and private data into separate branches of the tree. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921824/how-to-create-public-private-user-profile-with-firebase-security-rules/38923745#38923745

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for pointing to the right resource.