# Permission denied with Firebase Database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following form of database

```
Database
    users
        <UID>
            user
                <other information>
```

I am trying to read all my users in admin mode and only allow individual users to access their own information.

I am trying this rule:

```
"users": {
    "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && (auth.uid == $uid || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('user').child('admin').val() == true)",
        ".write": "auth != null &&  !newData.child('admin').exists() && (auth.uid == $uid || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('user').child('admin').val() == true)"
    },
    ".indexOn": ["userid"]
},
```

I am doing the following query and I see the following error:

```
allusers = $firebaseArray(firebaseDataService.root.child('users'));
```

> permission_denied at /users: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attach a listener to `/users`, the Firebase server checks whether you have read permission on `/users`. If not, it rejects the listener.

This is a common source of confusion for developers new to Firebase. Coming from a SQL/relation mindset, we are used to use security to perform (server-side) filtering. In Firebase you cannot use security rules to filter data.

I'll add a few relevant links below for further reading:

- [rules are not filters in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters)
- [Restricting child/field access with security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules/14298525#14298525)
- the Firebase [blog post on why denormalizing is normal](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html)
- an [article on airpair about data structuring](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data)
- a great [summary from a while ago on the firebase-talk group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/1p4O4Pc2w6k)

Comment: Frank, I am not using the security rules to filter data. For individual users, I go to the specific nodes. For admins, I go to /users. I am trying to make sure that only admins can go and read all user data and not anyone else.

Comment: If you want to give an administrator access to `/users`, you need to have a `.read` rule for that on `/users`.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't do that already. Works for me now that I have added it. Thanks