# Firebase database rules: accesing child data from parent

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Here are the rules for a list of objects. If you are authenticated you can access everything. If not, some objects are public, some aren't (boolean public property).
The rules bellow for the $object work fine if you try to access the object directly.

```
"list": {
  ".read": ???????????? ,
  ".write": "auth != null",
  "$object": {
    ".read": "auth != null || data.child('public').val() === true",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

But I also need rules to list ONLY the public objects if you are not authenticated. How can I set the read rules for a property of a generated $key inside its parent list? Something like:

```
"list":{
  ".read": "auth != null || data.child('$key').child('public').val() === true"
}
```

Comment: Mathew explains it below, but also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103 (and probably most other questions that mention the magic phrase "rules are not filters").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do filtering by .read

From: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

> Rules Are Not Filters
>
> Rules are applied in an atomic manner. That means that a read or write
>   operation is failed immediately if there isn't a rule at that location
>   or at a parent location that grants access. Even if every affected
>   child path is accessible, reading at the parent location will fail
>   completely.

Comment: Yeah, I read that. That's why I'm trying to pass the .read condition from the child to the parent. But there must be a way to filter server side what a user can or cannot see when listing objects. Am I wrong?

Comment: No you can't, that's exactly what this is saying. If you want to filter it by user you'll have to store it somewhere else by user.

Comment: So if there is no auth involved you can only choose between showing the whole list or not showing anything at all?

Comment: Not sure I understand but rules cannot filter but I think the answer is yes. You can filter based on sorting etc...

Comment: That is indeed correct. Firebase enforces the access control on the location where you attach a listener. So either you have read permission on `list` (in which case you can read everything under it) or you don't.