# Firebase Error: permission denied for Authenticated user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I need to have access of my "myapp.firebase.io/events" node's access to any authenticated users(authenticated by firebase auth) only. My rule is-

```
{
  "rules": {
     "events": {
      ".read":"auth != null",
      ".write":"auth != null"
      }
   }
}
```

And my activity is:

```
public class NotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView message,header;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
String from;
private Firebase ref;
private FragmentDrawerNotification mDrawerFragment;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMessage);
    header = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tHeader);

    from=getIntent().getExtras().getString("From");
    if(from.equals("Events"))
    {
        header.setText("Events: ");
        message.setText("");
        System.out.println(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
        //System.out.println("Events Auth"+ref.getAuth());
        ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/events");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String data =dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                message.setText(data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here 
    `System.out.println(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());`
is returning the logged in user's email correctly but `ref.getAuth()`
is returning null;
So,logged in users can't access the data and getting "Firebase Error: permission denied "
Here "events" is my key and "Today has an event" is my value.

If I use

```
{
 "rules": {
     "events": {
        ".read":true,
        ".write":true
      }
   }
}
```

I can access it, but I need to secure the database with authenticated users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing usage of legacy Firebase with new Firebase APIs.

```
//legacy: com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+
ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/events"); 

//com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Is your project in [console.firebase.google.com](https://console.firebase.google.com) console? If that is the case, please remove this dependency
`com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+`, include `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0` and follow this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) on how to get a database reference using the new Firebase APIs:

```
    //com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
```

I am assuming you have properly implemented [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users) already as it seems you have an authenticated user.

Comment: Actually, as a newbie a have mixed the use of new & previous sdk. Now my problem is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Happened to me also. :)

Comment: @Ajoy Das - I had the same issue and the quick fix was to update the rules {".read": true}, only for read access, somewhat similar post you can get an idea to resolve it in a simple way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules