# Firebase Security Rules, how to filter inside object

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Ok here is my problem I have object in firebase like this

`dev : {
   persons : {
      "111" : { name : "name1", surname:"surname1", uid: "userUID_1" }
      "222" : { name : "name1", surname:"surname1", uid: "userUID_2" }
   }
}
prod : {...}`

I want to read all persons whose uid must exactly match authenticated user id, I'm trying to make rules like this but it's not working ...

`{
    "rules": {
        ".read"  : false,
        ".write" : false,

        "dev": {
            "persons": {
              "$person_id" : {
                ".read" : "auth !== null && data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid ",
              },
            },
         },
    }
}`

Also when I'm setting ".read" : true, without any filter, inside "$person_id" It's not working also. Can you guys tell me what is my mistake, what I'm doing wrong in rules.

This rule still gets read denied inside persons, but if I make ".read": true outside "$person_id" it works, but i need to filter with some keys also.

`{
    "rules": {
        ".read"  : false,
        ".write" : false,

        "dev": {
            "persons": {
              "$person_id" : {
                ".read" : true,
              },
            },
         },
        "prod" : {
           ".read"  : false,
           ".write" : false,

        }
    }
}`

Comment: You cannot use security rules to filter data. If you run a query on `/persons` and you don't have read permission on `/persons`, the query will immediately fail.

Comment: Here is screen http://collabshot.com/show/sxcZ7W

Comment: Ok can you look at this link and tell me why they are saying this ->  "only messages from the last ten minutes can be read"
Here is link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

Comment: I know that documentation fairly well. Making a node unreadable after a time-out is not the same as trying to use security rules to filter data though. This is a common source of confusion for developers new to Firebase's security rules. To learn more, I recommend reading some of the [questions and answer in this list](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+rules+are+not+filters). Also see this [section in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's useful comment.