# Filter records which have specific value for a property

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase storage looks like this -

```
{
    notes: {
        note_1: {
            $uid: 0 | 1,
            title: "",
            description: "",
            priority: "",
            state: "",
            time: 0
        },
        note_2: {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

where $uid is the user id.

I have configured my rules like this -

```
{
    "rules": {
        "notes": {
            "$note_id": {
                ".read": "data.child(auth.uid).exists()",
                ".write": "(auth != null && !data.exists()) || data.child(auth.uid).val() === 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to query all the notes for a particular user. I tried with the below code -

```
mDatabase.child("notes").orderByChild(getLoggedInUserId())
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(getClass().getCanonicalName(), Long.toString(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

However, this does not work, as I don't have read permission on "notes".

Can anyone advise what should be done to retrieve data like this?

Comment: When you execute a read operation on `notes`, the Firebase server only allows that operation if you have read permission on `notes`. Since you don't, it rejects the operation. As a consequence: you cannot use security rules to filter data. This is [the default answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103) (that includes the common workarounds iirc) that I refer to, but if you search for "rules are not filters" you will find many more relevant answer.

Comment: Okay, I understand. But don't you think that either adds complexity to the design or introduces redundancy in data? Or both? I thought I'd just keep the notes list and will not keep a list of users. Now that I have to keep the notes inside the user nodes, I have to have them. And what about shared notes? Where do I keep them?

Comment: You don't have to keep the notes inside the user object; you only have to keep *a list of the keys of the notes* in the user object. See our documentation on [creating data that scales](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout) and this great article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/). While this structure indeed complicates the lookup (since you'll need extra code to read the notes themselves), it also is part of the reason why NoSQL databases scale so well.

Answer (score 0):

Change orderByChild for child

```
mDatabase.child("notes").child(getLoggedInUserId()
```