# Firebase - Get items I have read access to from endpoint

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

TLDR: How can I set up the DB access rules so that I can read all the items I have authorization to from a given endpoint?

I have a similar set of data in my Firebase database:

```
"employees" : [ {
    "first_name" : "Constance",
    "last_name" : "Smith",
    "createdBy: "vdBoGzI2i9f12er6ZcPjG9AiTip2"
  }, {
    "first_name" : "Agatha",
    "last_name" : "Carlton",
    "createdBy: "Tpg1mFR99meDV2QGT44pU6y7s1T2"
  },
  ...
}
```

I also have a list of application users:

```
  "users" : {
    "Tpg1mFR99meDV2QGT44pU6y7s1T2" : {
      "name" : "Alex Lund",
      "isAdmin": true
    },
    "vdBoGzI2i9f12er6ZcPjG9AiTip2" : {
      "name" : "David Peterson",
      "isAdmin": false
    },
    ...
  },
```

Basic users will have access just to the employees they created; the admin will be able to read everything.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "employees": {
      "$employee": {
        ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() === true || data.child('createdBy').val() === auth.uid" 
      }
    },
}
```

With this rules, an admin will be able to read `ref.child('/employees/0')`, but won't have access to `ref.child('employees')`.

How can I get all the employees I have read access to? Is running a query the only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the rules as you have them now, a query on `/users` won't work. Since you don't have read permission on `/employees` any listener on that location will immediately be rejected.

You probably want the rules to be like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "employees": {
      ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() === true"
      "$employee": {
        ".read": "data.child('createdBy').val() === auth.uid" 
      }
    },
}
```

With these rules administrators can read (and thus query) `/users`, while regular users can only access children that they created.

This is a common pitfall when it comes to Firebase Database security rules and is typically referred to as "rules are not filters". See the relevant [section in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters), this [original Q&A on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103) and any of the [questions in this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase%5d%20rules%20are%20not%20filters).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Frank, and the related reference links