# What Firebase Security rules should I use to read the messages?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want only those users to read the messages whose `uid` is equal to either or both the `to` or `from` fields of `message` or if the 'to' section of the message is set to `all`.

This is my database:

```
{
"intents" : {
  "intentFields" : "",
  "intentName" : "",
  "to" : ""
},
"messages" : {
  "-KViVgc7ZG051eMXP0-5" : {
    "from" : "Ed",
    "name" : "Ed",
    "photoUrl" : "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-pictures/100/male3-512.png",
    "text" : "Hello, I'm Ed",
    "timeStamp" : "1476880306",
    "to" : "all",
    "type" : "text"
  },
  "-KWmsuvm0uJIf01eHfyN" : {
    "from" : "Capyv3mxQsUUn2W1nPOgcJ0Ex9T2",
    "name" : "Aakash Bansal",
    "photoUrl" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-oQyA4HXVycc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAHKo/Ov0A0p0LjiY/s96-c/photo.jpg",
    "text" : "ho",
    "timeStamp" : "1479396273",
    "to" : "Ed",
    "type" : "text"
  }
}
}
```

I tries several rules, and read the Firebase documentation too. But none of the rules helped me achieve my result.

An example of the rules which I tried is :

```
{
"rules": {
  "intents" : {
    ".read" : "auth.uid === data.child('to').val()",
    ".write" : true
  },
  "messages" : {
    "$message": {
           ".read":  "auth.uid !== null",
           ".write": true
    }
  }
}
}
```

**whereas** the following set of rules works fine, although they don't achieve my desired result but they display all the messages in the app.

```
{
"rules": {
  "intents" : {
    ".read" : "auth.uid === data.child('to').val()",
    ".write" : true
  },
  "messages" : {
    ".read":  "auth.uid !== null",
    "$message": {
           ".write": true
    }
  }
}
}
```

Just to inform, I'm using firebaseui in the Android app to read the data. Please tell me if something is wrong in my understanding of 'firebase security rules'.
**EDIT** : Even the following set of rules are not working:

```
{
"rules": {
  "intents" : {
    ".read" : "auth.uid === data.child('to').val()",
    ".write" : true
  },
  "messages": {
    "$message": {
      ".read" : true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
}
```

The android code that I use to read the data is:

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new MessageAdapter(FriendlyMessage.class,
       R.layout.message_my,
       RecyclerView.ViewHolder.class,
       mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("/messages"));
```

Comment: How are you *reading* the messages? Because if you're trying to read `/messages` it will indeed fail with these rules. This is a common source of confusion, which we describe as [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) in the documentation and in [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103).

Comment: Where is your code? What are you actually reading? (hint: Puf's comment above is almost certainly the answer, but can't tell without code)

Comment: Yes puf, I've put firebaserecycleradapter at /messages, where should I put it to get the messages?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$message": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === data.child('to').val() || auth.uid === data.child('from').val() || data.child('to').val() === 'all' ",
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: no sir, it is not working. Although I have already tried this solution and some more similar solutions, but I am not getting any data in the app

Comment: What is not working? What are you attempting to do? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I am reading the messages by using recycler adapter in Android, and by 'not working', I mean messages are not being displayed in the app

Comment: And your auth.uid is `Capyv3mxQsUUn2W1nPOgcJ0Ex9T2`?