# Firebase rules to access specific child's value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The `childByAutoId` would be useful if you want to save in a node multiple children of the same type, that way each child will have its own unique identifier.

```
List:{
KJHBJJHB:{
  name:List-1,
  owner:John Doe,
  user_id:<Fire base generated User_id>
},
KhBHJBJjJ:{
  name:List-2,
  owner:Jane Lannister,
  user_id:<Fire base generated User_id>
},
KhBHJZJjZ:{
  name:List-3,
  owner:John Doe,
  user_id:<Fire base generated User_id>
}
}
```

I am trying to access the `List` with the help of the following code:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "/List")
```

The current user logged into the app is `John Doe`. When the user accesses the list, I want all the `List` child whose owner is `John Doe`(i.e. `List-1` & `List-3`) and ignore the other child values.

Do I have to do this in my application or can this be achieved via Firebase Security rules?

My current rule definition is:

```
"List":{
 ".read": "root.child('List/'+root.child('List').val()+'/user_id').val() === auth.uid" }
```

But this rule is not giving me any success. Any idea how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Have you tried using queries?

Comment: @gasho Yes, Using queries I can pull down the entire branch and then keep only the ones I need.
But actually I am trying to pull the required data from firebase itself so that I don't have to run any queries on my app side.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use security rules to filter the list. This is not possible and one of the common pitfalls for developers coming to Firebase from a SQL background. We commonly refer to it as "rules are not filters" and you can learn more about it in:

- the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters)
- this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103)
- our new video series [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)
- and many [previous questions mentioning "rules are not filters"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters)

The solution is almost always the same: keep a separate list of the keys of posts that each user has access to.

```
UserLists:{
  JohnUid: {
    KJHBJJHB: true,
    KhBHJZJjZ: true
  },
  JaneUid: {
    KhBHJBJjJ: true
  }
}
```

This type of list is often referred to as an index, since it contains references to the actual post. You can also find more about this structure in the [Firebase documentation on structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure).