# How to give write permission to parent node for admin/moderators user group and write permission for child node for every valid user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to give `.write` permission to `posts`' node for admins/moderators only. But for its two attributes `stars` and `starCount` any authenticated/valid user can write.

i.e I want to give `.write` permission to two nodes(stars and starCount) to every valid user. How to achieve this?

My current database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
      "$uid":{
      ".read":"auth.uid === $uid",
      ".write":"auth.uid === $uid",
      ".validate": "!data.exists() && newData.hasChildren(['id','photoUrl','role','username']) && auth.uid === $uid"
        }
    }, 

    "posts":{
      "$post":{
                ".read":"auth.uid != null",
                "stars":{
                      ".write":"auth.uid != null"
                },
                "starCount":{
                    ".write":"auth.uid != null",
                },
                "author":{
                    ".write":"auth.token.role.matches(/moderator$/)"   
                },
                "approvedBy":{
                    ".write":"auth.token.role.matches(/moderator$/)"
                },
                "body":{
                    ".write":"auth.token.role.matches(/moderator$/)"
                },
                "commentcount":{
                    ".write":"auth.token.role.matches(/moderator$/)" 
                },
                "title":{
                    ".write":"auth.token.role.matches(/moderator$/)" 
                },
                "timeStamp":{
                    ".write":"auth.token.role.matches(/moderator$/)" 
                },
                "url":{
                    ".write":"auth.token.role.matches(/moderator$/)" 
                },
                "uid":{
                    ".write":"auth.token.role.matches(/moderator$/)" 
                },
                "url_profile_pic":{
                    ".write":"auth.token.role.matches(/moderator$/)" 
                }
                    }
```

Database Schema Image:

[image: database_schema_image]

Comment: The rules look reasonable (although it's a bit much to parse quickly). If you're having trouble it's most likely because you're trying to read from `posts` with a user that doesn't have permission there. Firebase Database security rules can not be used to filter data. See [this section on the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters), [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103) or [any of these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-security%5D+rules+are+not+filters) for a lot more about it.

Comment: "posts" node have several attributes and I gave each attributes seperate .write permission according to my need. As my rule says any authenticated user can have .write permission for "stars" and "starCount" attributes.Unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Please post the [minimal complete code that is failing to read/write](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @Frank,I was defying 'Rules Are Not Filters',I need to restructure my database.