# Firebase Security Rules allowing conditional .read

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to create a firebase rule that allows users to read and write to child if a property of that child has a specific value. Let's say my database looks something like this:

```
"tasks": {
    "SDkh7s62jnd23d9": {
        "uid": "someuserid",
        "other": "datagoes here"
    }
}
```

Here is my current security rule:

```
"tasks": {
    ".indexOn": "_state",
    "$registerQueueKey": {
        ".read": "data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid",
        ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
    }
}
```

This rule restricts user write permissions, but it never lets a user read, even if the child they are attempting to read has a `uid` property that equals `auth.id`.

I then tested the following rule set:

```
"tasks": {
    ".indexOn": "_state",
    "$registerQueueKey": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
    }
}
```

Despite the `.read` permission being set to a permanent `true` value, the user still cannot read the `$registerQueueKey` child.

I then tested the following rule set:

```
"tasks": {
    ".indexOn": "_state",
    ".read": true,
    "$registerQueueKey": {
        ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
    }
}
```

Now I can read the child fine, so I attempted this final security rule:

```
"tasks": {
    ".indexOn": "_state",
    ".read": "data.child($registerQueueKey").child('uid').val() == auth.uid",
    "$registerQueueKey": {
        ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
    }
}
```

But this rule throws an error because the variable `$registerQueueKey` is undefined in the scope it is being used.

How do I accomplish a rule like this?

Comment: Firebase check read authorization on the location where you attach a listener. So either you can read from that location (and thus read everything under it), or you can't read from that location. This means that you cannot use security rules to filter content how you're trying here. This is known as [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) in the documentation, in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103) and in [these other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So do I need to restructure my database so that the value I am attempting to check against is the key of that child?

Comment: That would be one model that could work indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because you have not placed a wildcard:

```
"tasks": {
  "$uid": {
    ".indexOn": "_state",
    ".read": "data.child($registerQueueKey").child('$uid').val() == auth.uid",
    "$registerQueueKey": {
        ".write": "newData.child('$uid').val() == auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```