# Firebase customised rules

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

As of now I have below rules defined for my `customer` table.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "customers":{
      ".read": "auth != null", 
      ".write": "auth != null", 

      "$CID":{
        "UserId":{
          ".validate": "(data.exists() && data.val() == newData.val()) || newData.val() == auth.uid"
        },
        "CustomerName":{
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
        },
        "CustomerCode":{
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length<4"
        },
        "CustomerLimit":{}
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

As you can see, that I have `UserId` under `customers` branch which would hold the value of the logged in user id. Each authenticated User can create customers which basically belongs to that particular user and read/get only those `customers` which was created by him.

But now when I read from database as below:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("customers");
```

This retrieves all the data under the customers. So I was thinking to add some `read` rule to the existing one as in

```
"rules": {
    "customers":{
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid=loggedInUserId",  //something like this
    .....
    }
}
```

But I just couldn't find anywhere how it can be done here in the `rules`.

As an option I tried to write a `query` on `UserId` which always returned `null` even after passing valid logged in `UserId`.

```
Query query=mDatabaseReference.equalsTo(loggedInUserId,"UserId");
```

This method which I don't prefer as it would be best written in rules. Hope someone knows how we can add `rules` for this requirement.

Comment: Firebase read permissions are enforced when you attach a listener. Either you can read from the location you attach to (and thus can read everything under it) or you can't read from the location (and thus the listener is rejected). Rules cannot be used to filter data. See the [Firebase documentation for that topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters), [this original question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103) or any of [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh, so is it something like I need to create a node for each user [Not much users, some 10-50 in numbers] and then store customer details under that?

Comment: Yes. I added some links to my initial comment. Usually you'll only allow the user to read their specific nodes in the master list and then create a so-called index under each user's node with the keys of the items they have access to. Somewhat similar to `groups` node in the [documentation on creating scalable data structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout).

Comment: Thanks much @FrankvanPuffelen.. Pretty much clear now.. :)

Comment: Good good. This is one of the hurdles everyone stumbles into when learning about Firebase's security model. Unfortunately it typically means that you'll need to restructure your data to allow the use-case, so I hope it's not too late for that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen.. No no.. Its not too late.. I have just started working on the design.. :) I can restructure this.. :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Could you please help me on **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268560/firebase-rules-validation-and-catching-validation-fail-in-android-application)**. Its been much time I am trying to find solution for this..

Comment: Or could you please help on **[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274338/firebase-rules-validation-does-not-validate-data)**.. Am totally stuck on designing rules.. :(