# Firebase Rules validation and catching validation fail in android application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

**Design**

- A user who can login to the application
- Logged in user can create customers which will be stored under `node` whose value will be the current logged in userid

**Current DB values**

```
{
  "customers" : {
    "UserId1" : {
      "custId1" : {
        "customerCode" : "thk",
        "customerLimit" : "58866",
        "customerName" : "Test New "
      },
      "custId2" : {
        "customerCode" : "thh",
        "customerLimit" : "5698",
        "customerName" : "Yeth"
      }
    },
    "UserId2" : {
      "custId3" : {
        "customerCode" : "thh",
        "customerLimit" : "5886",
        "customerName" : "Test "
      },
      "custId4" : {
        "customerCode" : "tbh",
        "customerLimit" : "58669",
        "customerName" : "New Test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the rule currently defined for `customers` table in `firebase`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "customers":{
      ".read": "auth != null", 
      ".write": "auth != null", 
      "$CID":{
            "customerName":{
                ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
            },
            "customerCode":{
                ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length<4 && !newData.exists()"
            },
            "customerLimit":{}
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

Even though I've defined that a rule for `customerCode` i.e. it should have value less than 4 characters, it is allowing to insert 5 characters. Also how can I add a validation which validates uniqueness of `customerCode` for each `userId`? as of now it has `!newData.exists()` but its not working too.

Could anyone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can insert up to 5 characters because your `.length` for your `newData.val().lenght` start at 0, like an `array`. In other way, if you want to link uniqueness of a customerCode for each userId you should create a new table in your firebase database, Something like:

```
{
  "customers": {
    "UserId1": {
      "custId1": {
        "customerCode": "customerId1",
        "customerLimit": "58866",
        "customerName": "Test New "
      },
      "custId2": {
        "customerCode": "customerId2",
        "customerLimit": "5698",
        "customerName": "Yeth"
      }
    },
    "UserId2": {
      "custId3": {
        "customerCode": "customerId3",
        "customerLimit": "5886",
        "customerName": "Test "
      },
      "custId4": {
        "customerCode": "customerId4",
        "customerLimit": "58669",
        "customerName": "New Test"
      }
    }
  }
  "customerCode": {
    "custId1": {
      "customerId1": "thh"
    }
    "custId2": {
      "customerId2": "thk"
    }
    "custId3": {
      "customerId3": "thh"
    }
    "custId4": {
      "customerId4": "tbh"
    }
  }
}
```

Using this model, you can modify your rules to so something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "customers": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "$CID": {
        "customerName": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
        },
        "customerCode": {
          //Code shouls be string, less than 4 characters and it can't be already stored on customerCode table for the current userId
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length<3  && !root.child('customerCode').child(auth.uid).exists()"
        },
        "customerLimit": {}
      }
    }
    "customerCode": {
      "$CID": {
        "CustomerCodeId": {
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "auth != null",
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Maybe the rules are not perfect in the last example, but I'm sure that you can find the way about how it can fits in your app taking a look about [firechat database rules](https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/rules.json). I learned a lot looking that repository.

Comment: First of all, thanks much for your time.. But, its not problem with array starting from `0`.. It accepts 10 characters too.. There isn't any other work around for adding rule where I can check for this uniqueness of `customerCode` per `userID` because I feel extra linking table would be redundant...

Comment: Sorry it has not helped you, anyway, take a look about the repository that I linked you above, it is a good example with a lot of conditions for `firebase rules`. About your table, it will be more simple and less expensive at data level if you check that a unique `CustomerCode` is associated to a unique user than check if any user of your whole database have that `CustomerCode` associated. 

Another way can be just store in some place all the `CustomerCodes` which your users already used in the app, and just check if the code already exist when a new user want to create it

Comment: I can grab some idea with your suggestion for creating unique `customerCode`.. Thanks for the link and +1 for your efforts.. :) I will try to resolve this through the link you provided if at all I can.. :)

Comment: Don't worry mate, Firebase is getting a lot of new features each month since Google got it as platform, but some features still without to many examples or documentation. Hope that the answer helped you a bit. 
Also, if you want, take a look about the next link about database structure for Firebase: https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data

Have a good day and post your answer if you find the solution! It will be really great help for more people!

Comment: Sure mate.. I will post solution I adopted to resolve this once am done with this.. :) Have a good day you too.. :) Happy Coding..