# Firebase security rules. How to secure a path when queried using orderByChild()?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Sample collection of `users`.

```
"users":{
    "uid1":{
        "type":"normal"
    },
    "uid2":{
        "type":"normal"
    },
    "uid3":{
        "type":"admin"
    },
    "uid4":{
        "type":"super-admin"
    },
    "uid5":{
        "type":"disabled"
    }
}
```

Sample rules.

```
"rules":{ 
    "users":{ // I dont want the collection to be readable to everyone
        "$uid":{
            ".read":"auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write":"auth.uid == $uid"
        }
    }
}
```

Sample query.

```
firebase.database()
    .ref('users')
    .orderByChild('type')
    .equalTo('normal')
    .once('value')
    .then()
    .catch()
```

This query however returns a `Permission denied` error on path `/users`. How do I make the base collection secure but still the children are readable via `orderByChild()`?

Comment: This is known as ["rules are not filters" in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) and has been [covered quite some times before on StackOverflow too](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters). It essentially boils down to the fact that rules cannot be used to filter data, so you'll have to create a secondary index (i.e. list of keys) to query against. For one of the oldest answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the references. May I request an example `you'll have to create a secondary index to query against.` for the given situation above. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the examples already? There are quite a few of those samples, but you will have to modify them to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen