# The Firebase security rules not works

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a problem with Firebase rules. Basically I have a root folder called 'users', containing many usersIDs that again contains data, exactly like this:

```
users {
    userid1 {
        info_user {
            a: {
                a1: whatever
                a2: whatever       
                a3: {
                    a3.1: whatever
                    a3.2: whatever
                    a3.3: whatever
                    a3.n: whatever
                }
            }
            n: {} ...
        }
    },
    userid2 {}, ...n
}
```

Everything work fine when running the following code if there is no security rules, such:

```
{rules {".read"  : true, ".write" : true}}

function getUserInfo () {
    var dbRef = firebase.database();
    var myArray = [];
    dbRef.ref('users').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            myArray = (childSnapshot.val().a3);
            // do something
        });
    });
}
```

**My challenge** is to change the security rules without change the database structure.

So, I tried to do something like this:

```
{
    "rules" : {
        ".read"  : false,
        ".write" : false,
        "users": {
            "$userid": {
                "info_user": {
                    "a":{
                        ".read": "auth != null",
                        ".write": "(root.child('r').child('w').hasChild(auth.uid))",
                        "a1":{".validate": "newData.isString()"},
                        "a2":{".validate": "newData.isString()"},
                        "a3":{".validate": "newData.isString()"}
                    },
                    "n": {
                        ".read": "auth != null",
                        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is to read a node **a3** when user is authenticated.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Database read permission is enforced when you first attach a listener. So when you attach a listener to `dbRef.ref('users')`, you must have read permission to `/users`. In your security rules that is not the case.

To make the rules work, move the read permission up to `users:

```
{
  "rules" : {
    "users": {
      ".read"  : "auth != null",
      ...
```

Note that permission cascades down. So once you grant the user read permission on `/users`, they have access to all data under `/users`. You cannot take this permission away for a specific node under there.

This leads to one of the pitfalls of securing your Firebase Database: rules cannot be used to filter data. For more on this, see the [Firebase documentation on "rules are not filters"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters), this [answer about it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103) and many more of the [questions from developers struggling with the concept](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters).