# Firebase Database read whole node but depends on child node permission to return correct data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I setup rules on Firebase like this:

```
 "Data": {
  ".read": true,
    "data1": {
      ".write": "root.child('Permissions').child(auth.uid).val() == 'admin'",
      ".read": true
    },
    "data2": {
      ".write": "root.child('Permissions').child(auth.uid).val() == 'admin'",
      ".read": "root.child('Permissions').child(auth.uid).val() == 'admin'"
    }
}
```

and in my code, I want that when I read the node "Data", and data return should only contain "data1" node if users do not have "admin" permission, else both "data1" & "data2" are returned. Currently, when I get child "Data", both are return.

Comment: what if you remove the `".read": true` from the Data node?

Comment: then it will be permission deny when I try to read Data node

Comment: from another question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules) it seems that firebase doesn't allow "filtering" the data via the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data):

```
{
   "rules": {
     "foo": {
       // allows read to /foo/*
       ".read": "data.child('baz').val() === true",
       "bar": {
         /* ignored, since read was allowed already */
         ".read": false
       }
      }  
    }
}
```

if you allow read or write on a higher level (`".read": true`), it ignores other rules down the tree (`".read": "root.child('Permissions').child(auth.uid).val() == 'admin'"`).

Comment: do u have a solution for my problem?

Comment: i think you have to pull the data separately. `Data/data1` and `Data/data2` instead of `Data`