# addChildEventListener with firebase rules Confusion

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database has a child which is name is Messages and it has children user_id and also it has children which are title and timestamp such as:

- my firebase database

  - Messages

    - user_uid_1

      - Title
      - timestamp
    - user_uid_2
    - user_uid_3
    - ...

I want to add a addChildEventListener for Messages to determine if there are any change in Messages. this is very easy with this code:

```
myRef.child("Messages").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()...
```

how about firebase rules. if I made it public it works. but if I do like that child listener NOT working what should I add to my rules

```
{
  "rules": {    
   "Messages":{
       "$uid":{
            ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 18000000)",
            ".write": "auth != null"
   }
  },
   "$other":{
     ".read": true,
     ".write": "auth != null"
   }  
}
}
```

I want to read only messages from the last 30 minutes can be read so that I've added *".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 18000000)",*.

I think I should add something between "Messages" and "$uid" to addchild listener correctly.
thnks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase security rules are enforced when you attach the listener. If you're allowing reads on `/Messages/$uid`, then a listener on `/Messages` will be rejected since you have no read permission on that level.

This is known as [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) in the Firebase documentation, and means that you cannot use security rules to filter data. It has been covered quite a bit here on Stack Overflow already, so I suggest you check out some of the [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters). The oldest answer I can find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules/14298525#14298525).

Comment: So Puffen you said I should add 2 Message nodes, first one for Childlistener second one for if there is a change in message1, it will get data from Message2 0depeds on timestamp. {
  "rules": {    
   "Message1":{
       "$uid":{
       ".read": "data.child('tarih').val() > (now - 1800000)",
          ".write": "auth != null"
  }     
},
    "Message2":{
      ".read": true,
   },
     
   "$other":{
     ".read": true,
     ".write": "auth != null"
   }  
}
}