# Firebase nested rules

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to write a rule that will allow the user to read if and only if the nested child has the userId same as the auth uID

My database structure is as follows

```
"Chats":{
  "-KDKndo4sg47f7s9":{
    "-KDlmsn4hj4h4jk2n":{
        "fromId"    :  "uid1234n5g3h34g5g5h33j33g4g43h3h3"
        "text"  : "Hi, Can you please help me on this?"
        "toId"  : "uid234553sdfj3n4hjjh3jk3h3jk4k4nm3m3"
    }
  }
}
```

In this database structure, the `-KDKndo4sg47f7s9` is groupId/group key and `-KDlmsn4hj4h4jk2n` is messageId/message key.
Here is my rule

```
"Chats":{
        "$groupId":{
             ".read": "data.child('$messageId').child('fromId').val() === auth.uid" ,
             ".write":"newData.child('$messageId').child('fromId').val() === auth.uid"        
            }
      }
```

I tested read access to the rule by using the location
`/Chats/-KDKndo4sg47f7s9` and userId `“uid1234n5g3h34g5g5h33j33g4g43h3h3”`

The read and write are always denied. But if I'm writing the rule by passing the key directly as below

```
"Chats":{
        "$dealId":{
              ".read": "data.child(‘-KDlmsn4hj4h4jk2n’).child('fromId').val() === auth.uid" ,
              ".write":"newData.child(‘-KDlmsn4hj4h4jk2n').child('fromId').val() === auth.uid",        
            }
      }
```

Both read and write are allowed.
In short, I don't want to allow one user to read another user's messages. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This rule is incorrect:

```
"Chats":{
  "$groupId":{
     ".read": "data.child('$messageId')"
```

In the third line you have a string `'$messageId'`. More likely you want it to be `data.child($messageId)`, but that will give a syntax error because `$messageId` is not defined. Putting `$messageId` in quotes will remove the syntax error, but now it's just a literal string without the meaning you want.

My best guess is that your database structure means `/Chats/$groupId/$messageId`, in which case your rules should reflect that:

```
"Chats":{
  "$groupId":{
    "$messageId":{
       ".read": "data.child($messageId).child('fromId').val() === auth.uid"
```

With this rule you will be able to read a message if you are the sender.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Frank van Puffelen, but I want to access this path /Chats/$groupId  and want to read the messages that have fromId equal to auth.uid. Is that possible?

Comment: To read from `/Chats/$groupId` you need to have read permission on that path. This means that security rules cannot be used to filter data. This is known as ["rules are not filters" in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters). I recommend that you check out some of the [questions of many developers before you](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase%5d%20rules%20are%20not%20filters), including [this original one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103).