# Firebase Database Rules Unexpected Behavior

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am following the documentation to setup rules. It's a simple chat app and I want to retrieve only the recent messages (i.e. messages that were created in the last X mins). I found the following [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data) and tried exactly the same thing.

*Structure*

[image]

*Rules*

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$message": {
        ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > 1" // try allowing everything
      }
    },
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

It looks like none of the messages are retrieved. As a workaround for this, I'm doing it on the client-side like this:

```
messagesRef.orderByChild('timestamp')
  .startAt(Date.now() - 600000)
  .on('child_added', (data) => {
    // do something
  })
```

Hopefully someone can help me out with the rules!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you refer to secures the node of each individual message. So `/messages/-LDR_...ADvS` is accessible if its not too old.

But your query is reading from `/messages`, where you haven't granted anyone permission.

This is an example of one of the most common pitfalls in Firebase security rules: rules are not filters. For more on this I recommend checking the section [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) in the Firebase documentation, this [first question explaining it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14298525/209103), or some of the many [questions mentioning "rules are not filters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters) since then.

But things changed a bit earlier this year. While security rules can still not be used to filter data, they can be used to validate queries. For example, see this example from the [documentation on query based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query_based_rules):

> ```
> "baskets": {
>   ".read": "auth.uid != null &&
>             query.orderByChild == 'owner' &&
>             query.equalTo == auth.uid" // restrict basket access to owner of basket
> }
> ```

This allow reading from `/baskets` as your as you query by `owner == uid`. So now we grant the user access to `/baskets`, but only if they meet the condition our server-side security rules specify.

Unfortunately the last time I checked, the current `timestamp` was not available in query, making it impossible to write rules that only allow your workaround query.